# "bundling" functions in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Let's say I have:

```
val sayHello: Int => Unit = {_ => println("hello")}
val sayHi: Int => Unit = {_ => println("hi")}
```

And a function such as `foo` :

```
val foo: Int => Unit = {
  sayHi
}   
foo(123) //= prints hi
```

Is there a way of writing this:

```
val bar: Int => Unit = {
  i =>
    sayHello(i)
    sayHi(i)
}
```

without the `i` parameter? so that I can run both `sayHi` and `sayHello`?

I mistakenly had in my code the following:

```
val foo: Int => String = {
  sayHello
  sayHi
}
```

but this only uses the last expression and `sayHello` is not run.

In general, if this functions were to return anything other than `Unit`, let's say what is the idomatic way of bunlding these functions so that

```
val Hello: Int => String = {_ => "hello"}
val Hi: Int => String = {_ => "hi"}
```

what is the most idomatic implementation of the function bar:

```
def bar: Int => Seq[String]
```

such that:

```
bar(123) // returns List("hello","hi")
```

Comment: One comment: Your `foo` assignment value (`{ sayHello; sayHi }`) is an *expression*, evaluated one time. Each line is a statement evaluating to a function literal, and the last statement evaluated is the value for the expression. In order to define a single function literal, the parameter and fat arrow (`_ =>`) is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
def bar: Int => Seq[String] = i => Seq(Hello, Hi).map(_(i))
```

For the `Unit`-returning functions case, you can replace the `map` with `foreach`:

```
def bar: Int => Unit = i => Seq(Hello, Hi).foreach(_(i))
```

Comment: yeah I guess there is no escape. :)